# IBM IIB 10 SOAPRequest node with SSL

Tags: soap-client, ibm-integration-bus

I use a SOAP Request node to call a web service with a HTTPS URL. I have set Protocol TLSv1.2 and the URL but unfortunately the server gives back an error:

> An error occurred whilst performing an SSL socket operation. 
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.h: PKIX path
>   building failed: java.security.cert.CertPathBuilderException:
>   PKIXCertPathBuilderImpl could not build a valid CertPath.; internal
>   cause is: \n\tjava.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: The
>   certificate issued by *** is not trusted; internal cause is:
>   \n\tjava.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate
>   chaining error

I have not got any certification from server side to set it in a keystore but I think it is not needed. How can I say to the IIB to trust the cert from the server, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up a truststore containing the certificate(s) to validate the certificate of the server. This means adding the certificate(s) of the CA, that signed the cert of the server, or adding the server certificate if it is a self-signed one.

Typically, for SOAP nodes it's best to set this up at the integration server level:

```
mqsichangeproperties integrationNodeName -e integration_server -o ComIbmJVMManager 
  -n  truststoreFile 
  -v c:\truststore\server.truststore 

mqsichangeproperties integrationNodeName -e integration_server -o ComIbmJVMManager -n truststorePass 
-v integration_server::truststorePass

mqsisetdbparms integrationNodeName -n integration_server::truststorePass -u na -p password
```

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac56640_.htm

You can use the IBM key manager app included with MQ or the Java keytool to create the JKS truststore.

Comment: Thank you Attila. Ihave succeeded in implementing this process and it works at last but I exported certificate from the Windows cert store and inmported it into the truststore. I do not know wheather it was neccessary or not? Maybe it is enough to create a truststore?

Comment: When you create a truststore you can opt to include popular CA certs in it (when using the IBM tool), so if your cert is signed by one of them, you don't need to import anything else. Otherwise you need to import the signer's cert, or your cert if it's self-signed.